# Check a input field if it includes numbers and characters

Tags: java, input-field, checkvalidity

Heyho guys!

I have some street field which should normally includes the house number, so i want check the field if it contains characters and numbers (0-9). If both are right, the input is correct. Btw, i don't want use regex. Would be awesome, when someone can help me. I don't know how to check for it.

Thanks.

I tried this with user input, i tested for Railway 10

```
System.out.println("Street:");
strasse = input.readLine();

while(true) {
while (strasse.length() > 35) {
      System.out.println("Input has a limit of 35 signs. Enter again:");
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < strasse.length(); i++) {

      if (Character.isDigit(strasse.charAt(i))) {
         checkDigit = true;
      }
      else if (Character.isLetter(strasse.charAt(i))) {
         checkLetter = true;
      }

      if (checkDigit && checkLetter == true) {
         break;
      }
      else { // <= PROBLEM. You should give a chance to test all chars from address     
        System.out.println("Must contain at least 1 number or character. Enter again:");
        strasse = input.readLine();
      } 
   }
}
```

it gives no true back for checkDigit.

Comment: Why not use `Regex`? can you provide a sample of data?

Comment: Sample of data ? What do you mean? I want know if its also possible without regex.

Comment: An example of street address you will have to check

Comment: Street's looks like  Threeway 10,  Rail-Street 10b....

Comment: @CallMeBronxy: Are you working with `Swing`'s `JTextField`or somethingy similar or you doing that on Console/Terminal?

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the logic: you test for (digit && letter) in the for loop (this is fine), but then if the test is `false` you don't continue with the same address (you should): in the `else` you read a new line... there is no way you will get `digit && letter == true`

Comment: I don't get it. I would appreciate it, when you could edit the code for me.

Comment: its because i have to close the FOR-loop before i check both for true?

Comment: is there a first `strasse = input.readline()` before the `while`?

Comment: yes, there is. I checked your edit, i still dont get it.. when they aren't both true, its a false input for me, and he have the chance to edit his input. So it begins again from top. That's my current logic.

Comment: I EDIT my answer with a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any constraint on the street address format and just want to check if there is at least one character number and one alphabetic char, you can go for

```
boolean checkAddress(String address) {
   boolean hasDigit = false;
   boolean hasLetter = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
      if (Character.isDigit(address.charAt(i))) {
         hasDigit = true;
      }
      else if (Character.isLetter(address.charAt(i))) {
         hasLetter = true;
      }
   }
   return hasDigit && hasLetter;
}
```

**EDIT**
There was a closing ")" missing.
I tested with:

```
System.out.println(checkAddress("aksjdbakjs, 90."));  // => true  
System.out.println(checkAddress("aksjdbakjs asd asd")); // => false
System.out.println(checkAddress("...90.;;;")); // => false
```

**EDIT2**
Suggested solution for provided code

```
System.out.println("Street:");
strasse = input.readLine();
boolean strasseIstRecht = false;    

while(!strasseIstRecht) {
   if (strasse.length() > 35) {
      System.out.println("Input has a limit of 35 signs. Enter again:");
   }
   else {
      // re-initialise for each new input
      boolean checkDigit = false;
      boolean checkLetter = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < strasse.length(); i++) {
         if (Character.isDigit(strasse.charAt(i))) {
            checkDigit = true;
         }
         else if (Character.isLetter(strasse.charAt(i))) {
            checkLetter = true;
         }

         if (checkDigit && checkLetter) {
            strasseIstRecht = true;
            break; // ok address has both no need to continue the for
         } 
      }
      // Now check if we need to ask a new strasse
      if (!strasseIstRecht) { 
        System.out.println("Must contain at least 1 number or character. Enter again:");
        strasse = input.readLine();
      }
   }
}
```

You can simplify a bit by putting the `strasse = input.readLine();` first after the `while(...)` and removing both lines where it is done in the code above.

Comment: Thanks, im gonna test it.

Comment: I tested it, but doesnt worked. Im gonna copy my source in the opener thread, i didnt use an extra method for it, but i debugged the source, and it does not give back a true for digit, when a digit is entered.

Comment: ops, i did something wrong :D i added your post.

Comment: Can you please check my edit in opener thread?

Comment: Maybe i have to mention that read the input with a BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] addressArray = address.toCharArray();
Boolean goodValue = false;
Boolean foundSpace = false;
for (char ch : addressArray) 
{
    if(!foundSpace)
         {
             if(!((int)ch >= 48 && (int)ch <= 57)) break;
         }
    else if((int)ch >= 97 && (int)ch <=122) 
          {
               goodValue = true;
               break;
          } 
    if(ch==' ')foundSpace=true;    
}
```

This is pretty rough, but can give you an idea. Basically it tests all the characters in your address before a space to see if they are numbers, and then after the space, it looks for at least one letter.

Comment: You should rely on the `Character` class that provides helper functions to test family of characters. And `String$toCharArray()` does a _copy_ of the characters in the string which is not necessary.

Comment: I'll agree with you on that one, and try to edit my answer.